# Contour of the unit circle is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

$B = \{||x|| = 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed.

Attempt: We show $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$ is open. In other words, we must show that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$, $\exists $ a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \cap B = \varnothing$ Take $N = D^2(x,r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x - y|| < r\}$, and let 
$$  r=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{||x|| - 1}{2} & ||x||>1 \\
      \frac{1 - ||x||}{2} & ||x|| <1 
\end{array} 
\right.  $$

Suppose $D^2(x,r) \cap B \neq \varnothing$, then $\exists y \in D^2(x,r) \cap B$.

If $||x|| < 1$, then
$$||y|| \leq ||y-x|| + ||x|| < \frac{||x||}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + ||x|| < 1 $$
which is a contradiction.

If $||x|| > 1$, then
$$ 1 - ||y|| < ||x|| - ||y|| \leq ||y-x|| < \frac{1-||x||}{2}$$

$$ 1 - ||y|| < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{||x||}{2} \implies -\frac{1}{2} > \frac{||x||}{2} - ||y|| > \frac{1}{2} - ||y|| \implies||y|| > 1$$ this is a contradiction. Therefore, $N \cap B = \varnothing$, and $B$ is closed.

Is this correct? can someone give some feedback? thanks

Comment: +1 for the lovely use of LateX. Also, the proof seems fine to me. However, the tags are not quite correct. I will change them.

Comment: Your idea is correct. You are using the fact that "A subset B of X is closed iff its complement an open set".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me offer a completely different approach. The function $x\mapsto \lVert x\Vert$ is continuous. We know $\{1\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, whence $f^{-1}(1)=S^1$ must be closed. In particular this shows any circle $\{\lVert x\rVert =r\}$ is closed.