# Is $S^1, S^1 \times S^1, S^1 \vee S^1$ closed?

Tags: algebraic-topology

There seems some more obvious reasons for that $S^1, S^1 \times S^1, S^1 \vee S^1$ closed? I am thinking of seeing $S^1,S^1 \vee S^1$ as the subcomplex of some CW complex, such as $S^2$, and seeing $S^1 \times S^1$ as the subcomplex of a torus, hence they are closed? (Hatcher Page 520: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATapp.pdf)

Comment: What is your topologies? Do you consider your spaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 2):

What I will present is a generalization of an argument given  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479575/contour-of-the-unit-circle-is-closed) on a similar question. Although, I am not sure it will be correct or any easier than what you already know. I know taking inverses as is done here is not quite justified; so  if someone can justify it , or show why it cannot be justified, I would appreciate it.

We will use the Euclidean norm, $p:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, to show all three. The function $p:x_0↦||x_0||$ is continuous, because norms always are. Everything else works because of this, keep it in mind when reading all cases.

$\textbf{Case 1 }\;\; X=S^1$

Let $z_0 \in X$. We have $||z_0||=1$. We know ${1}$ is closed in R, whence $p^{−1}(1)=S^1$ must be closed. In particular this shows any circle {∥x∥=r} is closed.

$\textbf{Case 2 }\;\; X=S^1 \times S^1$

Let $z_1 \in X$. We can represent $X$ as a 4-parameter map to $R^3$ centered at the origin , where $r,R, \phi, \theta$ are the radius of the cylinder, radius to the origin, vertical angle and angle on the plane respectively.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hence, $p(X) = [R-r,R+r]$ and $p^{-1}([R-r,R+r])=X$ is closed.

$\textbf{Case 3 }\;\; X=S^1 \vee S^1$

Let $r$ be the radius of $S^1$ and embed $X$ into $R^2$, where the identified points are at the origin. We have $p(X)=[0,2r]$ and so $p^{-1}([0,2r])=X$ is closed.

Case 2 could be made a lot shorter using case 1, but it would seem like magic if you were not familiar enough with the torus.

Edit: $p$ is always non-nengative, I fixed the images as I wrote this in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

Being closed is a property of a subset of a space, not of space. You do not present your spaces as subsets of another set, so the question is meaningless.

However, all three spaces are compact, so whenever you embed them in a Hausdorff space, they will be closed in that spaces.